# How to set SetPlatformApplicationAttributes using SNS API via python script

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to set the Platfrom application attributes for a SNS topic via python using the boto3 library.

Below is the snippet of script

```
client1 = boto3.client('sns',region_name="us-east-1",aws_access_key_id=access_key,aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key)

def getSNSattr():
    response = client1.set_platform_application_attributes(
    PlatformApplicationArn='arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:63124104179:testTop1',
    Attributes={
        'key':'SuccessFeedbackSampleRate',
        'value':'100'
    }
    )
```

Below is the error I am getting. The aws documentation doesn't have an example for python and not much helpful. I am not sure what I am missing here. Please help

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sns2.py", line 20, in <module>
    getSNSattr()
  File "sns2.py", line 15, in getSNSattr
    'key': 'SuccessFeedbackSampleRate'
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 317, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 615, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidParameterException: An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the SetPlatformApplicationAttributes operation: Invalid parameter: PlatformApplicationArn Reason: Wrong number of slashes in relative portion of the ARN.*
```

AWS doc for reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_SetPlatformApplicationAttributes.html

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.set_platform_application_attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ARN you put in PlatformApplicationArn is not a platform ARN, but a Topic ARN. If you want to set the attributes for the topic, consider using [SetTopicAttributes API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/goto/WebAPI/sns-2010-03-31/SetTopicAttributes). I would also use double-quotes, as attributes are JSON formatted.

All this can easily be tested using AWS CLI:

```
$ aws sns get-platform-application-attributes --platform-application-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:app/GCM/My_App

{
    "Attributes": {
        "FailureFeedbackRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/SNSFailureFeedback",
        "EventDeliveryFailure": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:Test",
        "EventEndpointDeleted": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:Test",
        "EventEndpointUpdated": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:Test",
        "Enabled": "true",
        "EventEndpointCreated": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:Test",
        "SuccessFeedbackRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/SNSSuccessFeedback"
    }
}

$ aws sns set-platform-application-attributes --platform-application-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:app/GCM/My_App --attributes '{"SuccessFeedbackSampleRate": "100"}'

$ aws sns get-platform-application-attributes --platform-application-arn arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:app/GCM/My_App

{
    "Attributes": {
        "FailureFeedbackRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/SNSFailureFeedback",
        "EventDeliveryFailure": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:Test",
        "EventEndpointDeleted": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:Test",
        "SuccessFeedbackSampleRate": "100",
        "EventEndpointUpdated": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:Test",
        "Enabled": "true",
        "EventEndpointCreated": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123456789012:Test",
        "SuccessFeedbackRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/SNSSuccessFeedback"
    }
}
```

Use SetPlatformApplicationAttributes API with the **Application ARN** if you want to set attributes for an Application, or the SetTopicAttributes API with the **Topic ARN** if you want to set attributes for a Topic. Also use double-quotes as attributes are JSON formatted.

The code should look like:

```
def getSNSattr():
    response = client1.set_platform_application_attributes(
    PlatformApplicationArn="arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:63124104179:app/GCM/testApp1",
    Attributes={
        "SuccessFeedbackSampleRate":"100"
    }
    )
```